# issue with folders ownership

Tags: svn, permissions

I've an issue with files ownerships in unix.

I have a drupal website and the "files" folder needs to be owned by "www-data" in order to let the users to upload files with php.

However I'm now using svn and I need all folders and files to be own by "svnuser" in order to work.

So now, I guess I need to add both users to a group with proper permissions. I'm not sure what exactly to do, could you tell me what are the exact necessary steps ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group that has necessary permissions for all files, then add `svnuser` and `www-data` to this group.

Comment: I've done it, but it doesn't work. The files group is now www-data and svnuser is added to www-data. The group has full permissions (775). I'm sure the user is added, I checked: www-data:x:33:svnuser

Comment: Group permissions don't take effect while a user is logged in.  Is that the issue?  Make sure svnuser is logged out and then back in.